# create proxy in c# and use in httpclient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, proxy, httpclient, instagram-api

i am using [Instasharper](https://github.com/a-legotin/InstaSharper) (private Instagram API).
my app is Instagram bot for follow and unfollow ,
and i read some where that for one ip there is limitation,
that we can only use 5 account login for one IP in Instagram.
but i have 300-500 user.
should i use proxy?

i dont know how to create proxy for each user and use it.

this is how we create instagram private api and use it

```
var api = new InstaApiBuilder()
            .UseLogger(new SomeLogger())
            .SetUser(new UserCredentials(...You user...))
            .UseHttpClient(httpHandlerWithSomeProxy)
            .Build();
```

i should create proxy and use it in httpclient 
.UseHttpClient(httpHandlerWithSomeProxy)
can u give me some links or helps
tanks

Answer (score 1):

I have solved something similar before by creating an http client with a custom message handler.
Am I right in thinking the parameter to `UseHttpClient` is an HttpClient?

If so,
e.g.

```
public class MyHttpMessageHandler : System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //...(your implementation here)
    }
}
```

...then:

```
MyHttpMessageHandler myMessageHandler = new MyHttpMessageHandler();
HttpClient httpHandlerWithSomeProxy = new HttpClient(myMessageHandler);
var api = new InstaApiBuilder()
        .UseLogger(new SomeLogger())
        .SetUser(new UserCredentials(...You user...))
        .UseHttpClient(httpHandlerWithSomeProxy)
        .Build();
```

of course you can pass parameters to `MockHttpMessageHandler`'s constructor if you want to give it some data.

Comment: UseHttpClient is an HttpClient? yes it is , its accept httpclient as parameter

Comment: what is this :MyHttpMessageHandler ? what it do?

Comment: MyHttpMessageHandler is your own class derived from HttpMessageHandler. It implements the actual logic of the request that HttpClient makes, so it enables you to customize it to do something different from the default behaviour.

Comment: i want to create proxy thats what i want,but i dont know how

Answer (score 1):

i do this and i think its right way 
and i should this for every user
but how can i find proxy adress and port. can anybody explain that to me 
tanks

```
    InstaApi _instaApi;
    var userSession = new UserSessionData
    {
        UserName = "",
        Password = ""
    };
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Proxy = new WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8888"),
        UseProxy = true,
    };
    _instaApi = new InstaApiBuilder()
            .SetUser(userSession)
            .UseHttpClientHandler(handler)
            .Build();
```

Comment: Hello, You can find Proxy address here but you have to check it first to see if it work correctly before using it.  http://spys.one/free-proxy-list/US/